# How do I implement a point-and-click user interaction model?

Tags: c++, user-interface, mouseevent

Context: I'm making a simple solar system simulation in c++/OpenGL.

Research: I've tried searching but I only ever find articles on widgets and flash and HCI stuff.

Problem: I'd like the user to be able to click on an actor, and then maybe deselect, or select something else. Maybe select multple actors at once. If the actor is destroyed, I'd like the selection to go away. I'd like the actor to know it's been selected.

I know how to get the mouse coordinates, and how to see if a click happened on this actor or that actor, or the closest actor. What I don't have any experience doing is modelling the interaction. I can think of something like CSS's model of active, hover, and pressed, so some sort of state, I guess. But then I get into the problem of ownership, and what happens if that actor is deleted or needs to be deleted? Should there be some sort of observer?

Obviously I don't understand the problem enough to try and solve it for my purposes. I have no experience with callbacks or events or whatever. Can anyone point me to some articles, guides, or similar help?

Comment: I think your question is far too broad; from the FAQ: *"Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."* Could you narrow it down a bit?

Comment: That's why my question wasn't "how do I do this?" but rather "where can I learn how to do this?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using smart pointers for your actors (e.g. `boost::shared_pointer`) then you can solve the ownership problem easily by using weak pointers for your selection. For example:

```
std::set<boost::weak_pointer<Actor> >  selected_actors;
```

You just need to be aware that any pointer you retrieve from that set might be invalid, but Boost pretty much forces you to check that.

---

For the actor to know when it's selected, I would just make some virtual member functions that are called by your selection code, e.g.:

```
class Actor {
public:
  ...
  virtual void on_selected() { }
  virtual void on_deselected() { }
  ...
};
```

---

If you also need the actor to keep track of *whether* it's selected, do it like this:

```
class Actor {
bool selected;
public:
  Actor() : selected(false) { }
  ...
  void selected() { selected = true; on_selected(); } // not virtual
  void deselected() { selected = false; on_deselected(); } // not virtual
  ...
protected:
  ...
  virtual void on_selected() { }
  virtual void on_deselected() { }
};
```

---

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. I am using weak pointers already, and this does solve the problem of ownership. The set of selected actors is a good idea, too, and if one is deleted, it can be removed from the set. If I do have a large list of selected actors, would it make more sense to have an actor ask if it's selected? That way the list of selected actors would be the authority in whether an object is selected.

Comment: Yep, you could do it either way, or both ways. Or, if this fits your architecture, you could pass a `bool selected` into every function on `Actor` that needs this information (e.g. `draw(bool selected)`) so that actors don't need access to some global selection manager.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a quick look at [Qt](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/resources/getting_started). It will do all that you want and more. For the most part, you can take what you want and leave what you don't.

It also has a good way to wrap-up/integrate OpenGL code with the more friendly elements of a user interface that you're after.